# What are the best foods for cutting calories?

Tags: weight, weight-loss, calories

Imagine that you accumulate fat VERY easily besides being unable to always prepare your food and eat healthy, and not having much time to exercise.
If you wanted to cut calories, what would be the foods that have low calories but leave you satisfied? like jelly(Gelatin) but more nutritious.

Comment: Vegetables! I'd also look into whether or not you're insensitive to certain foods (I think a blood test can determine this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything with alot of fiber.  Fiber makes people feel full without adding many calories.Insoluble fiber does not add calories and soluble fiber adds less calories per gram than other carbohydrates. Whole grains and vegetables have good fiber, and if you are craving something sweet, fruit has better nutrition and better fiber than cookies and candies.
https://fiberfacts.org/fibers-count-calories-carbohydrates/